# ssh-user-config ERROR with Cygwin on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ssh, cygwin

I'm following the [How To Get SSH Command-Line Access to Windows 7 Using Cygwin](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/).

At the `User Configuration of SSH` step (half of the above page, more or less) I got the following error:

```
$ ssh-user-config
*** ERROR: /home/User is set in the account database as your home directory
*** ERROR: but it is not a valid directory. Cannot create user identity files.
```

How to proceed?

Comment: Could you possibly explain what step you're on? What you've tried already?

Comment: The step is indicated in the question (edited). Please let me know if I can provide more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573763/i-am-unable-to-find-the-etc-passwd-file-in-cygwin

In short, you have to:

1. Find the /etc/nsswitch.conf file (open it with notepad or smt like
   that)
2. Add this line in: db_home: /%H

That will change your Cygwin home directory to be equal to your Windows user profile directory.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the /etc/passwd file lists the wrong home directory, or the directory /home/User was deleted.

This might be corrected by opening the passwd file and correcting the home directory for your user, or if it is correct: making the directory in question.

Comment: Well. What may I do in this situation?

Comment: @KcFnMi Fix `/etc/passwd` or create `/home/User`

Comment: `/home/User` actually exists. How to fix `/etc/passwd`?